# Java Creating a array and strings from user input

Tags: java, arrays, string

Im writing a program that first takes input from the user as an int then constructs an array that the user then types in individual characters that builds a string from that. i've written some code but I've come up with a form of writer's block and i don't know where to go from here. any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: im stuck on getting the string from the input into the array im getting an error where a method is not applicable. ill make in the code where the error is happening.

Example:

How many strings? 2

Enter string #1:

Enter an alphabetic string followed by enter: t

Enter an alphabetic string followed by enter: e

Enter an alphabetic string followed by enter: s

Enter an alphabetic string followed by enter: t

Enter an alphabetic string followed by enter: %

Enter string #2:

Enter an alphabetic string followed by enter: one

Enter an alphabetic string followed by enter: two

The strings you entered are:

test onetwo

code is below:

```
    package workfiles;


   //George Flamburis
   import java.util.*;

   public class Hw3 {

private static Scanner numScan;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numstring=0;

    numScan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (numstring <= 0 ){
        System.out.print("How many strings? ");
        numstring = numScan.nextInt();
        if (numstring<1){
            System.out.print("Please enter a positive (> 0) number.");
            }
        }

    String[] stringarray = new String[numstring];

    for (int i = 0; i < numstring; i++) {
        //ERROR HAPPENING IN THIS CODE BELOW!!!
        stringarray[i] = inputAlphaString();
    }


    numScan.close();
}

public static String inputAlphaString(Scanner aScan) {

    Scanner strScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String t = "a";
    String hold = "";

    while(t.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")){
        System.out.println("Enter an alphabetic string followed by enter: ");
        t = strScan.nextLine();
        hold = hold + t;
    }
    strScan.close();
    return hold;

}

//added [] into the method name and int to i
public static void printSArray(String[] sArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= sArray.length; i++)
            System.out.print(sArray[i] + " ");
    System.out.println();
}


}
```

Comment: Describe what you are actually stuck on, or what you have tried and why it didn't work

Comment: How come this `one` be an alphabet:`Enter an alphabetic string followed by enter: one`?

Comment: @AlexR updated! sorry about that

Comment: @PritamBanerjee because they are supposed to be strings not int.

Comment: `inputAlphaString();` needs a Scanner as it's argument but you're not passing anything. You should probably change it to `inputAlphaString(new Scanner(System.in));`

Comment: Or you can simply refactor the `inputAlphaString` method so that it wouldn't need any arguments to be passed in to it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.